2004 Toyota Sienna
I had my Toyota Sienna engine resealed, transmission resealed last October.  Within the last 6 weeks, my van cranks up just fine, I can back up, but when I go to accelerate, the RPMs go up, but no movement.  Once I keep pushing, it finally gets going, and I'm fine the rest of the day with all stops and starts.  This only happens the first time I use the van in the morning.  Any idea what's going on?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like either there is low transmission fluid. If the fluid is fine, you may have a stuck solenoid or valve in the valve body. More than likely you'll need some professional service to get it right.

The transmission guy who resealed and replaced gaskets in my transmission last October is the one who's saying that it needs to be replaced. Why didn't he suggest this last October?

Can you define what you mean by “resealed”? Did they only replace the input shaft seal or rebuild the transmission as well?
If they only touched the input shaft seal it’s unlikely this is repeated to the seal job. It sounds like possibly something with correlation between transmission range sensor or input shaft speed sensor data, or possibly a sticking valve or weak solenoid in the valve body if the transmission although that’s not something Toyota is know for unless you failed to ever service the transmission

The transmission fluid was checked and is good. An additive was placed in the fluid to see if it would help. I've had the transmission checked as recommended. Now they say I need a Rebuilt transmission  that will cost $4500 + $1800 for labor, but it comes with a 3yr warranty. He's also looking for a Japanese transmission that is less expensive. With my van being a 2004, I'm not sure it is worth it.

I will ask about the things you questioned, and if they were addressed. Thank you for your feedback!!!
